# How do I query posts from post type taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, dynamicquery

I use this code to match

current default post title slugs
with 
category term slugs

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

$current_post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name' );
        $args['category_name'] = $current_post_slug;
        $args['post_type'] = 'post';
```

But I want to match current default post title slugs with post type custom taxonomy term slugs.
My custom taxonomy name is "itemscategory", my custom post type name is "items".

So I changed the code into

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

$current_post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name' );
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'itemscategory',

    )
),
        $args['category_name'] = $current_post_slug;
        $args['post_type'] = 'items';
```

But it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?